# Why am I getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass some values from one ViewController to another and to some extent, I succeeded. String variable were passed successfully, the problem is with String Arrays. Don't know why but every time I run the app, I run through the EXC error.

This below is my external Class where variables were declared.

```
import UIKit

class externalHandler: NSObject {

    var handlerKey:String!
    var handlerValue = [String]()

    init(handlerKey:String, handlerValue:[(String)]) {
        self.handlerKey = handlerKey
        self.handlerValue = handlerValue
    }
}

var keyValues = externalHandler(handlerKey: "", handlerValue: [String]())
```

Below is a different class from where I am accessing these variables and setting them with a new Value. This is the code I'm accessing the 'handlerValue' variable

```
keyValues.handlerValue.append("Some")
```

I've tried the other way too

```
keyValues.handlerValue += "Some"
```

but that too throws me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Is it something I'm doing the wrong way?

Comment: So, " EXC_BAD_ACCESS" is the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initializer has the second parameter declared in a funny way. It should be a `[String]`, not a `[(String)]`:

```
init(handlerKey:String, handlerValue:[String]) {
    self.handlerKey = handlerKey
    self.handlerValue = handlerValue
}
```

Also, the `+=` operator for arrays changed recently -- that last line should be:

```
keyValues.handlerValue += ["Some"]
```

Comment: `(String)` is same as `String` (unless compiler can't figure it out due to some bug, which it did have), and use `append` instead of `+=` to add one element

Comment: tried keyValues.handlerValue += ["Some"] but still getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Comment: I was using Xcode 6 Beta 4, and so I was not getting desired result with Nate's suggestion. Beta 6 does it . just follow Nate's Instructions